# how to troubleshoot Object.const_get failing in rake but not in console?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have these lines of code that I use as a Factory to create objects:

```
class ServiceProcessor    
  def self.create(service, logger)
    classified_name = service.name.to_s.split('_').collect! { |w| w }.join << "Processor"
    logger.warn "Creating service proc, classified name: #{classified_name}"
    service_proc = Object.const_get(classified_name).new
    ... check respond_to etc. 
    return service_proc
```

The first line might be odd, it needs to be refactored. I can use these lines to create various Processors:

```
 class AlphaProcessor < ServiceProcessor
 class BetaProcessor < ServiceProcessor
 etc...
```

So these processors can be created in my specs and via the console. They can be created in rake as well -- but only some of them. Two of them are failing:

```
WARN 2012-01-27 08:54:18 -0800 (25626) Creating service proc, 
 classified name: AlphaProcessor 
ERROR 2012-01-27 08:54:18 -0800 (25626) 
 Failed for service #<Service _id: 4f203c171d41c83b3b000003, _type: nil, 
 deleted_at: nil, name: "Alpha", enabled: true> 
ERROR 2012-01-27 08:54:18 
 -0800 (25626) Exception: uninitialized constant AlphaProcessor ERROR 
 2012-01-27 08:54:18 -0800 (25626) Backtrace: 
 ["/mnt/hgfs/kodiak/lib/service_processors/_service_processor.rb:33:in 
 `const_get'", 
 "/mnt/hgfs/kodiak/lib/service_processors/_service_processor.rb:33:in 
 `create'", "/mnt/hgfs/kodiak/lib/update_engine.rb:28:in `block in 
 update_all'",
```

So the question is, **how should I go about figuring out why these two (out of 9) would fail, but only in Rake?** I can see that Rake and the Console are loading the same environment (a few `puts` in the environment.rb), so I doubt that's it. I'm stumped on what could be causing this or where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a Kernel#require to the top of your rake file to load the proper classes? Also, how are you defining the rake task? I've been able to do this for pulling in my class constants:

```
task :my_task => :environment do
  ...
end
```

Also, check your filenames. Make sure that a class named "AlphaBravoTangoProcessor" is in a file named 'alpha_bravo_tango_processor.rb', **not** a file named 'alphabravotango_processor.rb'.

Comment: I will try that Kernel thing, thanks for the tip. I wonder why the ones that are working don't need require... I am pulling in the env: `task :nightly_tasks => [:check_connection, :environment ] do ...`

Comment: I updated your answer to include the final solution: rake seemed to be confused by the name of the file that the class was in and it broke const_get.